# Resolve dependency in Kconfig

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

Is it possible to resolve the dependencies of an option using Kconfig utility?

For instance, I have my `.config` and I would like to add an option `CONFIG_FOO`
and its dependency automatically without using `menuconfig`.

Note that using `make oldconfig` does not work, it just gets rid of the
additional option `CONFIG_FOO` I just added.

I know that there is a Python implementation of Kconfig :
[Kconfiglib](https://github.com/ulfalizer/Kconfiglib) but I have to do it in C.

I did read the C code and I have an overview of what is going on there but I
just do not get where is dependency solving for an option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you want and dependencies are not linear. FOO could depends on (BAR or (USB and SPAM)). How do you resolve this? If you have a specific driver, you can check direct dependencies easily (syntax is simple), but you cannot generalize. About Python and C: use the right tool for the task. Note: I asked 20 years ago to build reverse dependencies on Kernel (like we have in distributions), but it seems few people care (just professional configure kernels in a very controlled way)

Comment: Yes, it's possible, The approach has been developed first in terms of Yocto distribution and now can be used wider. See the python + shell scripts to merge configuration: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/yocto-kernel-tools/tree/tools/merge_config.sh. (@GiacomoCatenazzi JFYI)